# How do I measure impedance at high power?

Tags: impedance, measurement, high-power

I need to measure the impedance of a passive device at its operating power, about 100-watts, and its operating frequency, from 0.1-MHz to 10-MHz. The venerable "operating impedance bridge" produced by Delta Electronics comes close to meeting the need, but the operating frequency only goes down to 0.5-MHz, it's analog and it's expensive.

I would, of course, prefer a high-power version of the low-cost automated VNAs that have flooded the market in recent years, but I can't find any such thing with an internet search.

Do I have to build my own?

Comment: What's the range of impedances you are expecting? 10 MHz is not break-neck fast, it might be sufficient to include a series shunt resistor and measure the current that way.

Comment: I need to measure impedance in the single-digits to a few 10's of k-ohms. I may have to rig up a system of GPIB-controlled signal generators and oscilloscopes to measure the amplitude and phase of the current through a sense resistor. I'm hoping for an even more "off the shelf" solution.

Comment: Perhaps the use of a "directional" coupler should be useful. But at low frequencies ...  http://www.shx-sh.com/en/upfiles/2014122291911422.pdf  One begins at 30kHz.